# permutation optimization in tensorflow

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, permutation

#### Problem setup

I have a batch of `4x4` matrices, containing real valued entries.

```
L = tf.placeholder('float32', shape=[None, 4, 4], name='pairwise-loss')
```

I'd like to find a batch of 4-permutations such that each 4-permutation minimizes the sum of applying the permutation as one-hot mask.

```
def get_best_permutation(L_):
    '''
    Returns a batch of permutations `P` such that `tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(P) * L_, axis=(1,2))`
      is minimized for each batch element.

    Args:
        L_: real valued tensor of shape [None, 4, 4]

    Returns:
        P: tf.int64 tensor of shape [None, 4]

    '''
    raise NotImpelmentedError()
```

The permutation size is small and constant, typically 3-4. However batch size is expected to be very large. Ideally, everything should be done inside a graph, and on GPU so less data transfers.

**EDIT** it's safe to assume all matrix entries are positive.

#### Background

This is to implement something similar to [Permutation Invariant Training](https://www.upwork.com/leaving?ref=https%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fpdf%2F1704.01985.pdf).

#### Quick and dirty solution

One can just pre-compute all possible permutations since they are small, then apply all of them in parallel. Finally apply `tf.argmin` to find the best one. However I'd like a more efficient solution.

Comment: More efficient than brute force for three or four elements sounds unlikely. Is this the bottleneck in your model?